# AngularJS Custom Resource URL being overwritten

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a custom resource defined as such:

```
app.factory('SpaceGroupService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('api/SpaceGroup/:id', { id: '@id'},
{
    'parkingSpaces': { method: 'GET', url: 'api/SpaceGroup/:id/ParkingSpaces', isArray: true }
});
}]);
```

The idea is to pass in an ID of my space group object to return all parking spaces in that group. When I call

```
SpaceGroupService.query()
```

While running on my local iisexpress it's hitting the correct service url: 
/api/SpaceGroup

But when I do:

```
spaceGroup.$parkingSpaces({ id: spaceGroup.SpaceGroupId }, function (parkingSpaces) {
                spaceGroup.parkingSpaces = parkingSpaces;
            });
```

It is querying my restful service as: 
/api/SpaceGroup/2

instead of:
/api/SpaceGroup/2/ParkingSpaces

I'm somewhat new to angularJS and I know my route works on my API controller so I'm just trying to get this service to work properly. Any ideas why this overwritten URL isn't called?

Answer (score 0):

I'd would write your service like this instead:

```
app.factory('SpaceGroupService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return 
{
    ParkingSpaces: $resource('api/SpaceGroup/:id/ParkingSpaces', {},
    {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: { id: '@id'}, isArray: true }
    }
}
}]);
```

And then call it like this instead:

```
  SpaceGroupService.ParkingSpaces.query({ id: someId });
```

You can set up multiple resources in the service this way - and you can define multiple methods too (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).  It also means that Angular will honor your $resource url.